# How can we obtain array length in emu8086 assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, emu8086

I want to obtain the array length in assembly for emu8086. With `length` or `sizeof` I get an error:

> error-wrong parameter

Can anyone help me with other ways to find the length of an array?

Comment: If emu8086 doesn't support any way of getting the length of an array at assembly-time, then you can either store the array length as a separate element, or reserve some value as an "end of array" marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A**. You can calculate the difference between the end of the array (`$`) and its start (`offset array1`). You need to do the calculation right after the array definition. If you didn't, `$` would already be pointing much further down in the program.

```
array1 db 65,66,67
array1len equ $ - offset array1

array2 db 'Any string is an array too!'
array2len equ $ - offset array2
```

**B**. If the array is known to have some special terminating value, then searching for that value is also a way to find the length of the array. Consider an ASCIIZ string, a string of ASCII characters terminated by a zero byte:

```
string db 'Just a text.', 0
```

Next loop will produce the length (12, not including the zero byte of course) in `CX`:

```
  mov  si, offset string - 1
back:
  inc  si
  cmp  byte ptr [si], 0
  jne  back
  lea  cx, [si - offset string]
```

Comment: Note that this calculates the size in bytes, regardless of `db` or `dw` or larger elements.  I don't know if EMU8086 supports MASM-style `lengthof array1`, but you can do `arr3len equ ($-arr3) / 2` if it uses DW for 2-byte elements.  (The `offset` keyword isn't needed in this context because dereference wasn't an option.)